# The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'FontNameId' on type 'ConferenceManagementSystem.Models.FontName' is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

New to the website here, and I had tried several solutions which solved similar problems but to no avail, so would really appreciate for some help.

The error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'FontNameId' on type 'ConferenceManagementSystem.Models.FontName' is not valid. The navigation property 'AbstractFileFormat' was not found on the dependent type 'ConferenceManagementSystem.Models.FontName'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

The code snippet:

```
namespace ConferenceManagementSystem.Models
{
    [Table("AbstractFileFormat")]
    public class AbstractFileFormat
    {
        [Key]
        public int AbstractFileFormatId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title_HorizontalAlignment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("FontNameId")]
        public int Title_FontName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title_FontSize { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Title_Bold { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Title_Italic{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name_HorizontalAlignment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("FontNameId")]
        public int Name_FontName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name_FontSize { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Name_Bold { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Name_Italic { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address_HorizontalAlignment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("FontNameId")]
        public int Address_FontName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address_FontSize { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Address_Bold { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Address_Italic { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email_HorizontalAlignment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("FontNameId")]
        public int Email_FontName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email_FontSize { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Email_Bold { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Email_Italic { get; set; }

        public float LineSpacing { get; set; }

        public int ConferenceId { get; set; }

        public virtual Conference Conference { get; set; }

        public virtual FontName FontName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Second snippet:

```
namespace ConferenceManagementSystem.Models
{
    [Table("FontName")]
    public class FontName
    {
        [Key]
        public int FontNameId { get; set; }

        public int Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AbstractFileFormat> AbstractFileFormats { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I did this, and it worked.

Add another property in `AbstractFileFormat` class, that corresponds to the Foreign Key in the `AbstractFileFormat` table. i.e. the field that points to the `FontNameId` field in the `FontName` table. Something like this:

```
public int FontNameId { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("FontNameId")]
public int Email_FontName { get; set; }
```